# IIS Rewrite Provider : How to log requested URL?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have IIS 10 running on Windows Server 2019

I'm rewriting some URL's using a provider written in .Net

I would like to log all the URL requests sent to this provider. Is that possible please ?

For example if the provider receives "/url?parameter=x", I would like this string to be saved.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Here is my code

```
Partial Public Class URLManager
    Implements IRewriteProvider
    Implements IProviderDescriptor
            
    Public Function IRewriteProvider_Rewrite(Value As String) As String Implements IRewriteProvider.Rewrite
        Dim Output as string 
        
        'Do some processing of the requested URL        
        Output = Process(Value)
        
        Return Output
    End Function

    Public Iterator Function IProviderDescriptor_GetSettings() As IEnumerable(Of SettingDescriptor) Implements IProviderDescriptor.GetSettings
        Yield New SettingDescriptor("MainApplication", "Main Application Identifier")                             
    End Function

    Public Sub IRewriteProvider_Initialize(settings As IDictionary(Of String, String), rewriteContext As IRewriteContext) Implements IRewriteProvider.Initialize        
        Dim MainApp as string 
        
        settings.TryGetValue("MainApplication", MainApp)        
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A request has a client with a remote endpoint.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.remoteendpoint?view=net-5.0

Comment: "HttpListenerRequest.RemoteEndPoint : Gets the client IP address and port number from which the request originated." I don't need the IP adress and the port number. I need the URL requested. For example : "https://www.example.com/page?param=value" or how to save the parameter sent to the function : IRewriteProvider.Rewrite

Comment: The URL is in the headers : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.headers?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the question is not : "How to get the URL ?", the question is "How to log it ?" I already have the URL in the function : `IRewriteProvider_Rewrite(Value As String)` The parameter Value is URL

Comment: Where do you want to log the results?   The server has little access to the IIS file system.  You either want to log to a network drive (not on IIS) or database.  Yes it is possible.

Comment: I want to log them to the server dive. Do you have an idea how to do that please ?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525410(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0):

IIS can record all original URL in Log file before URL rewrite.

[image]

The record of this is URI in URL, including all parameters.

Or you can install **[Advanced Logging](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging)** on IIS, it also can log original URL and rewritten URL.